# Run/Call bat file with Python in Spyder

Tags: python-3.x

I want to run/call an existing bat file in Python Spyder.

I tried the following two codes. Both start the command window but then it quickly quits/exits. I would highly appreciate your help.

Option 1)

```
Import os


os.system("path....\\xxx.bat")
```

Option 2)

```
Import subprocess


subprocess.call ("path....\\xxx.bat")
```

Comment: please post real command you're using... and use `check_call` to get exception on failure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: still not the real command... try to call from a console, and check the errors it prints...

Comment: thanks your your answers. Unfortunately, I cannot share the real command here. But I can tell you that the command X calls another command y and provides y some variables.